# gerResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_name); <-- Not working

Tags: java, android

I have a NavDrawer. I want to define the items in the list. There seems to be a slight error that for the life of me, I cannot pick up.

Here is my code. (Forgive me if it is something so small..)

**MainActivity (onCreate)**

```
String[] drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
```

**res/values/strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="items">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <item>Item 2</item>
        <item>Item 3</item>
        <item>Item 4</item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
        <item>Item 6</item>
    </string-array>

    <string name="drawer_open">Open Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="drawer_closed">Close Navigation Drawer</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Can you post error as well?

Comment: What is type of `drawerListViewItems` object?

Comment: @MysticMagic "items cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: It seems you have imported `android.R` instead of your local R.java?

Comment: @Glenn-- Thanks. I feel rather stupid now.. It is working perfectly. Enjoy your day!

Comment: @Rijnhardt Not really, that's normal to android developer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think problem is with  `R`. Check to see if you have imported the wrong R class.

if you have included in your source file `import android.R;` Replace it with you package specific `R` . For example: import `com.example.R`

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Me being myself, imported the wrong one.. I had another project in my workspace...

Gosh, I feel stupid now. Enjoy your day!

Answer (score 0):

If the above is not the case, double check if you have placed the string resource in the `/res/values/<filename.xml>.`

I had a brain fart moment with a project that had a number of flavours and I had mistakenly created the file under `/res/<flavour>/values/<filename.xml>` and ended up banging my head for 10 minutes because of it.